# C programming : padding in structure

Tags: c, memory, padding

I am using

```
processor architecture: x86_64
OS                    : Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch) 64-bit
GCC compiler ver.     : 6.3.0
```

If I compile this code -

```
struct test {char a; int b;}
test;
printf("%ld", sizeof(test);
```

then the output is -   8 I assumed it because of 4 bytes padding , I mean 1+3+4 
now I tried this code-

```
struct test{char a; double b;} 
test;
```

and this gave me 16 bytes, then I thought, may be it is because of 8 bytes padding, i.e.- 1+7+8 now when I tried this code -

```
struct test{char a; long double b; char c;}
test;
```

this gave me 48 bytes

In my system using gcc , int = 4 byte, double = 8 byte, char = 1 byte ,long double = 16 byte.

My question is how this works? Why not a uniform padding?

Comment: "Alignment" is the keyword you should look into.

Comment: This line `printf("%ld", sizeof(test);` is missing a bracket. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Anyway should be `printf("%zu", sizeof(test));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You changed the pattern with your third structure.  If you had this third structure instead, you would have gotten numbers consistent with the pattern for the first two:

```
struct A { char a; int b; };         // 1 +  3 +  4 =  8
struct B { char a; double b; };      // 1 +  7 +  8 = 16
struct C { char a; long double b; }; // 1 + 15 + 16 = 32
```

Now, when you put another `char` after the `long double`, you only *need* one more byte for that, but the compiler adds another 15 bytes of padding:

```
struct D { char a; long double b; char c; }; // 1 + 15 + 16 + 1 + 15?!
```

I think the question you're really trying to ask is, why does it do that?  It does that because of arrays.  The C standard says that there can never be any padding in between the elements of an array.  But for the interior padding to do its job of keeping `b` properly aligned to 16 bytes, `struct D` must itself be aligned to 16 bytes.  If `struct D` were 33 bytes long, the second element of an array `struct D dee[2]` would be misaligned.  So the compiler must insert more padding at the *end* of `struct D` to make its size a multiple of its alignment.

Comment: you said - "keeping `b` properly aligned to 16 bytes", but instead of doing this , the compiler could aligned it to 8 bytes. so b will have two parts. because i have 64 bit cpu , what it will do using 16*8 bits of data(content of b) at once?. this could save memory instead of 16 bytes alignments.

Comment: Nowadays when we say "64-bit CPU" we mean that its _pointers_ are 64 bits wide.  That doesn't mean that it has no use for greater than 64-bit alignment. As it happens, on x86-64, `long double` is 128 bits wide, and is required by the [ABI](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/402129/mpx-linux64-abi.pdf) to be aligned to 128 bits as well; that document doesn't say _why_ it makes that requirement, but I would guess that either the data bus is at least 128 bits wide, or the authors wanted to leave open the possibility of its being that wide in the future.